# How to change bgcolor of each item in array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-email

(Keep in mind, this needs to be compatible with HTML email so tables and outdated attributes are a necessity - such as bgcolor.)

I am trying to change the bgcolor of all TDs with a certain id that is defined in an array in JavaScript. I have tried numerous similar examples with no luck, for example:

```
var yellowIDs = ["1201", "1204", "0116"];

for (i = 0; i < yellowIDs.length; i++) { 
    document.getElementById(yellowIDs[i]).bgcolor = "#ffff00";
}
```

HTML PORTION

```
<td id="1201" align="center" width="35" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #fff;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;background-color: #D83826;line-height: 100%;padding: 5px;" valign="top">Sun</td>
```

I'm sure I'm missing a lot, and I appreciate any and all help.  Thank you.

Comment: CSS `background-color` will work even in e-mails. The problem may be that you're not allowed to execute JavaScript in an e-mail message, or the fact that you use IDs starting with a number (it's valid in HTML5 but some JS implementations don't allow to `getElementById('123')`).

Comment: @pawel I haven't tried this yet in the email itself. I'm trying to work it out in a browser first.  Then I'll take on that battle :)

Comment: change the IDs by adding a letter at the start, like `id="td1201"` (an in the array) - the error you mention in the comments is probably caused by `getElementById` returning `null` for IDs starting with a number. But I think it's a waste of your time because no sane e-mail client will allow you to execute JS.

Comment: BTW maybe post a fiddle? Here it works fine for both numerical and alphanumerical ids: http://jsfiddle.net/45wusjds/1/

Comment: In gmail/outlook u cant use JS, u can only use inline styles, like <div style='background-color:red;'>text</div>

Comment: @SergeySob I will be adapting this script to the proprietary script my ESP uses.  I will be handled on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work, you're interested in [HTMLElement.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute)

```
var yellowIDs = ["1201", "1204", "0116"];

for (i = 0; i < yellowIDs.length; i++) { 
    document.getElementById(yellowIDs[i]).setAttribute('bgcolor',"#ffff00");
}
```

Comment: `bgcolor` is not valid css property.

Comment: @mgwhitfield TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(yellowIDs[i]).setAttribute')

Comment: @AlexChar but it is (well, at least it was in the old days of HTML3.2 ;)) a valid attribute, as in `<div bgcolor="#f00"></div>`

Comment: @AlexChar bgcolor is not the CSS, but an attribute of the <td>.  I know it's odd, but with HTML email a lot is...

Comment: try document.getElementById(yellowIDs[i]).style.background = "#ffff00";

Comment: You re setting attribute instead of css here...this will do nothing

Comment: @SergeySob what? why? http://jsfiddle.net/45wusjds/2/ - does exactly what it should and gives the expected result of setting a background color.

Comment: Oh, you re using table attrs, nice, forgot that thingie, my bad. Wont work in gmail/outlook, though since they dont allow JS. But if he prints it on server side as html, and not client side runnable JS, then this will work, true, true, sorry :)

Comment: I did eventually get this to work, but only in a fiddle.  I think something is wrong with the rest of the document, but I'm unsure of what.  I'm working on transferring it to my ESPs proprietary script now so it will work server side.  At that point I'll be able to troubleshoot more.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Outlook won't render 3 digit color codes properly also

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
document.getElementById(yellowIDs[i]).style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
```

Comment: I have tried this as well and get similar errors as I mentioned in my comment above "null is not an object...."

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Javascript in emails. Most clients will block it. You're stuck with changing these bgcolors by hand.

Comment: Thank you. I will be adapting this script to the proprietary script my ESP uses.  I will be handled on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```js
var yellowIDs = ["1201", "1204", "0116"];

for (i = 0; i < yellowIDs.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(yellowIDs[i]).style.background = "red";
}
```

```html
<div id="1201">aaa</div>
<div id="1204">aaa</div>
<div id="0116">aaa</div>
```

Also i suggest to use as id something like `div1201` for example.

for HTML 4:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

but for html 5:

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home
>   subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not
>   contain any space characters.

[source](http://www.w3.org/)

Comment: Thank you!  I did adjust my id names.  I appreciate the reminder.